# Robolectric how to test DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern()

Tags: java, android, kotlin, robolectric

I have test unit test with Robolectric:

```
@Test  
@Config(qualifiers = "en")
```

And in tested method something like this:

```
val locale = context.resources.getString(R.string.language_locale)
val pattern = android.text.format.DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale(locale), "EEE, d MMM")
return SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale(locale)).format(date)
```

But it looks like Robolectric has problem with that because there is no shadow for DateFormat class and DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern() giving wrong results.

**Any idea how to write unit test for method with  DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern() without writing shadow for whole class ?**

Update:

On real device it looks nice but on Unit Test instead of

> Fri, Mar 3

result is:

> Fri, 3 Mar

Comment: You should share both results in your excerpts. The output you expect and the output from the `Robolectric` framework.

Comment: @PatrickW Updated

Comment: Robolectric being a test framework, the expectation is that your input should be consistent with the locale for which you choose. Are you ensuring that your input is consistent with the expected locale?